# Is there a word for stopping in the middle of the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Lately, I suffer from an unusual habit. I simply don't finish my sentence while typing and I don't even notice it. Afterwards when I take a look at (for instance) the email I sent, I can clearly see that I've stopped in the middle of the sentence. I wouldn't believe my colleagues if I couldn't see my email history. So I'm wondering if

Comment: What you have to understand is that

Comment: (incidentally, this is called aposiopesis)

Comment: @JohnClifford True, but your answer is obviously ignoring

Comment: stutterer ! :O)

Comment: "Good evening, I'm Piers Morgan. What I lack in journalistic integrity," (end;audience laughing). This was from an SNL Parody.

Comment: Okay, I'll just go and

Comment: 'Aposiopesis' may sound fancier, but isn't applicable unless you're doing it deliberately for effect. And you claim this isn't the case (and dissimulation would attract an 'unclear what you mean' close-vote). I'd advise you to select Max Williams's answer instead.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are correct. I didn't notice the word deliberately, so i though that it was a perfect match, not because it sounds fancier. Did you by any chance down-voted my question and his answer?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realise you weren't referring to it being done deliberately Memet, sorry about that. Max seems to have you covered though. :)

Comment: hmmm.......ADHD??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When talking, this is usually referred to as "**trailing off**", or "trailing off in the middle of a sentence".  Eg

*"Susan started telling John about the weekly sales report, then trailed off, looking over his shoulder."*

*"I'm always trailing off halfway through a sentence, especially when I haven't had a coffee yet."*

Alternately, the trailing off describes' someone's *voice*:

*"Susan started telling John about the weekly sales report, then her voice trailed off as she looked over his shoulder."*

Either of these are acceptable, although I think the latter (where the voice trails off, not the person) may be more correct.

When referring to typed or written text, however, i don't think that this is quite right without the addition of the ellipsis (...) which indicates that the trailing off is a deliberate part of the sentence.  For example, this is trailling off:

*"She hasn't been here for months.  In fact, now I think about it..."*

which tells the reader that the speaker has trailed off.

If it was just this:

*"She hasn't been here for months.  In fact, now I think about it"*

It just looks like a mistake.  However, you could, i think still *call* it "trailing off", eg:

*"Lately, I suffer from an unusual habit. I trail off in the middle of sentences, while typing, and I don't even notice it."*

and I think people would understand what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

You could say that your sentences are [truncated](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+truncated):

> shorten (something) by cutting off the top or the end.
>
> "a truncated cone shape"
>
> synonyms: shorten, cut, cut short, curtail, bring to an untimely end; abbreviate, condense, reduce, prune
>
> "the program may need to be truncated"

"Sorry, I noticed that I've been truncating sentences in my emails."

You might also combine the answers and say something like "I've been trailing off in my emails and truncating sentences."

Comment: Truncated is good but (to me at least) it implies an *action* of truncation, ie that it's been done deliberately rather than by accident.

Answer (score 2):

This rhetorical device is called **aposiopesis**.

> Aposiopesis (/ˌæpəsaɪ.əˈpiːsɪs/; Classical Greek: ἀποσιώπησις, "becoming silent") is a figure of speech wherein a sentence is deliberately broken off and left unfinished, the ending to be supplied by the imagination, giving an impression of unwillingness or inability to continue.

Comment: No; aposiopesis _is_ the deliberate rhetorical decision to do so, and this is not the situation here.

Comment: I assumed that due to the obviously-intentional humorous way the OP ended the question, the preceding part was meant to be an amusing anecdote making it look like there wasn't a joke coming, but I may have misinterpreted it.

Comment: That _would_ be confusing. But he didn't add the joke in the original.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Incidentally I also found a blog post from 2008 titled "I am a man of, often unintentional, aposiopesis which..." but I guess that was used more for effect than an acceptable definition.